# Ansible Determine Operating System

Tags: ubuntu, ansible

As part of my deploy script I wanna check which operating system I am deploying to. I used `ansible localhost -m setup` and as they say in the documentation this outputs a lot. Is there a way I can just access the ubuntu distro I am using? Ideally I want to find if the box is running Trusty or Precise

Comment: What about lsb_release?

Comment: `cat /etc/*release` is what I use, for any Linux system.

Comment: @Xen2050 In this case I think it makes more sense to use ansible's built in functionality which probably calls what you both mention to set the fact

Answer (score 35, accepted):

### `ansible_distribution_release`

The fact is called `ansible_distribution_release`.  If you are running Ubuntu 14.04, the fact would read "**trusty**".

<sup><sub>Two other example values: `ansible_distribution_release` would be "**xenial**" for Ubuntu 16.04 and "**precise**" for Ubuntu 12.04.</sub></sup>

### `ansible_distribution_version`

You can also look at the fact `ansible_distribution_version`.  For Ubuntu 14.04, you would see "**14.04**".

<sup><sub>Two other example values: `ansible_distribution_version` would be "**16.04**" for Ubuntu 16.04 and "**12.04**" for Ubuntu 12.04.</sub></sup>

Here is an example task that you could put into a playbook to install the `build-essential` package only on Ubuntu 14.04:

```
- name: Install build-essential for Ubuntu 14.04 only
  apt: name=build-essential state=present
  when: ansible_distribution_version == "14.04"
```