# Ansible playbook to determine OS release

Tags: ansible

I'm simply trying to check the version of ubuntu on all my servers.  Based on [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1010836/ansible-determine-operating-system) I see that ansible has a `ansible_distribution_version` but this playbook does not show how I would simply just have it print out the ubuntu version, ie ubuntu 14.04, 16.04, etc

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can do one at the time

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: yes
  become: false
  tasks:
  - name: Distribution
    debug: msg="{{ ansible_distribution }}"
  - name: Distribution version
    debug: msg="{{ ansible_distribution_version}}"
  - name: Distribution major version
    debug: msg="{{ ansible_distribution_major_version }}"
```

See the results:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Distribution] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Ubuntu"
}

TASK [Distribution version] ************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "18.04"
}

TASK [Distribution major version] ******************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "18"
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Or you can use a more advance configuration iterating facts:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: yes
  become: false
  tasks:
  - name: System details
    debug: msg="{{ item }}"
    with_items: 
    - "{{ ansible_distribution }}"
    - "{{ ansible_distribution_version }}"
    - "{{ ansible_distribution_major_version }}"
```

And a more compact results:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [System details] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=Ubuntu) => {
    "msg": "Ubuntu"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=18.04) => {
    "msg": "18.04"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=18) => {
    "msg": "18"
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

In both cases is a good practices to get the info using facts instead of `shell` or `command` modules.

Comment: response I get from ansible_distribution_major_version is "Hello world!"
using ansible 2.6.0

Comment: just for completeness if someone wants to get the release name e.g. Bionic: `ansible_distribution_release`

Answer (score 1):

After very research to find out Ubuntu 20.04 version then we have got released a version using ansible version-2.5.1

```
- hosts: localhost
  become: true
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
  - name: System details
    debug:
      msg: "{{ ansible_facts['lsb']['release'] }}"

  - name: ubuntu 18
    shell: echo "hello 18"
    register: ub18
    when: ansible_facts['lsb']['release'] == "18.04"

  - debug:
     msg: "{{ ub18 }}"

  - name: ubuntu 20
    shell: echo "hello 20"
    register: ub20
    when: ansible_facts['lsb']['release'] == "20.04"

  - debug:
     msg: "{{ ub20 }}"
```

Answer (score -1):

I got it, to check the OS version here is the playbook

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
    - name: Check Dist Version
      shell: cat /etc/os-release
      register: response

    - debug: msg="{{ response.stdout }}"
```

Comment: It is much better if you use the ```gather_facts: True``` instead of running shell commands.

Comment: As advised by @Robert, this is not the ansible way of doing this kind of task.

Comment: the downvoted answer (not by me) and, curiously, it is the only one that worked for me, the others fail, which seems to be related to an Ansible 2.9 bug...

Comment: They asked specifically for the ansible_distribution_version, not output from a shell command.

Comment: Note that ansible already parses this file for you: `"distribution_file_path": "/etc/os-release",`